# How to call restful service from spring 2.5

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have two application. 1 application is old version of spring that is based on xml configuration. There are no annotations used. From This application stored procedures are used for CRUD operations. For Poc I have developed a simple CRUD application using spring boot, I have exposed them a restful services.

Now I have to consume this new rest service in my old application. How to do it? I am looking to use restful template which is not available in spring 2.5.

Comment: Mind to comment on my answer?

Comment: @Hille: Thanks Buddy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already mentioned, [RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) is only available as of spring version 3.0 or later.

So, the basic options I see are:

1. update your spring version from 2.5.x to at least 3.x
2. use an external lib offering help in consuming rest services
3. make up your "own"

If the first is an option, go for it. I can not really comment on the second option, but I'm pretty sure there is no widely used, actively maintained library using something comparable to spring's template pattern.

So I'd go for the third option. The quotes around "own" are there because I'd make use of the spring RestTemplate code (as of spring version 3.0). As spring is using an Apache 2.0 license you may use and repackage part of the code.

Start from a stripped down version of [RestOperations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestOperations.html) (versions later than spring 3.0 add methods to this interface, e.g. using `ResponseEntity`, so really start from 3.0). Continuing with the code from [RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) you may get frustrated at first, as spring is dragging in quite a few classes introduced in spring 3.0 (`MessageConverter` stuff, ...). But this is due to the modularity of spring, not due to large amounts of code.

Just make sure you have a canonical way of mapping the spring packages to your own name space, so not to get confused.

Incorporating spring's source code using patterns you use in other projects (like the template mechanism) is imho a great way of getting a deeper understanding of the code base you usually just consume; another benefit.